# .htaccess rule not blocking access to images on live site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've explored a lot of options and solutions and nothing seems to work, and I don't know what else to try but to ask for this specific issue.

I have a website where I serve images through PHP, so I want to block access to the original images.

I've tried adding .htaccess in those subfolders to "Deny from all", worked in dev, didn't work live.
I've tried adding deny rules to root .htaccess, didn't work in dev or live.

and now my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404       /error/?Error=404
ErrorDocument 403       /error/?Error=403

RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule     ^images/1/*/.*\.(jpg|png)?$                          [F,NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^images/2/*/.*\.(jpg|png)?$                          [F,NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$                index.php?P1=$1        [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?P1=$1&P2=$2  [QSA,NC,L]
```

for reference, images are structure as:

> /images/[1,2]/[folder1,folder2,...]/[number].[jpg,png]

eg:

> /images/1/folder1/10.jpg

In dev, I can't access the images as expected, but they're still accessible on live site.

It's impossible that htaccess file isn't being parsed/read, because the index rewrite rule works fine and as expected.. What am I missing here? Is it possible that something in those 2 lines differ between versions of apache, and my local system parses it fine while the server fails?

For server setup, I'm running apache behind nginx proxy (managed through CWP).

Options tried:

`RewriteRule  ^images/1/*/.*\.(jpg|png)?$  [F,NC,L]`

`RewriteRule  ^images/1/folder/.*\.(jpg|png)?$  [F,NC,L]`

`RewriteRule  ^images/1/specificFolder/.*\.jpg?$  [F,NC,L]`

(all 3 variants above for these below ones)

`RewriteRule  ^images/1/*/.*\.(jpg|png)?$  /error  [F,NC,L]`

`RewriteRule  ^images/1/*/.*\.(jpg|png)?$  error.php  [F,NC,L]`

`RewriteRule  ^images/1/specificFolder/([0-9]+).jpg?$  /error/403  [NC,L]`

`RewriteRule  ^images/1/specificFolder/([0-9]+).jpg?$  error.php  [NC,L]`

Most worked on DEV, none worked on LIVE. I still don't know the cause.

Server differences (changing either isn't an option):

`Dev: Apache/2.4.52 (Win32) PHP/7.4.27`

`Live: Apache/2.4.56 (Linux/CentOS 7)  PHP/7.2.17`

Comment: Is it possible that Nginx is configured to directly serve the images, so Apache isn't kicking in for those resources?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Unfortunately that is not the case, I can see image requests in the apache access log, giving back a happy 200
[...] "GET /images/1/covers/1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 53193 "-" "User Agent"

Comment: I haven't used `RewriteRule` in a long time, but I think they always require three parameters, "Pattern", "Match" and "Flags", and you are missing the middle one. Can you try just adding `-` for that?

Comment: Even better, is it an option to move the images somewhere that is not be accessible in the first place? This means there's no magic server rules that need to be setup and tested when migrating between systems.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've tried with the dash, and with a redirect to error page (in the same way rest of the htaccess works, all work fine on DEV, none work live. I am losing my mind here.

Comment: When in doubt - enable some rewrite logging, and find out what actually happens. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging